# macOS: Window and View menus show duplicate items

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a document-based app, with separate View and Window menus in the main menu. The app uses `.xib` files, not storyboards.

Trouble is, both menus show duplicate items. I have customized both of them in the Interface Builder. My `NSDocument` implementation validates needed menu items, but it can't catch the automatically added ones. Even changing the top-menu titles won't affect the default items they are receiving.

Where can I find a setting, which determines which menu will get which items? I've searched intensely and gone through every file in my project, but either can't remember or can't search the correct words to find the solution.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

[image: View Menu] [image: Window Menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you originally created the *View* menu by copying the *Window* menu? That could explain the duplication. If you control-click the xib in Xcode and select *Open As* -> *Source Code* you will see the plist data. Search for `systemMenu`:

```
<menu key="submenu" title="Window" systemMenu="window" id="Td7-aD-5lo">
```

If your *View* menu has the `systemMenu="window"` parameter, try deleting it.

Comment: Thank you - this saved me from a mental breakdown. Kind of strange that these properties/attributes can't be inspected in the IB.